# Best way to store quarter and year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What would be the best way to store Quarter and Year in database? I have payments table and I need to assign quarter/year so that it's easy to tell for which quarter the payment was made.

I was thinking on:

a) adding two int columns to each payment
b) adding another table and add possible values up to 5 years ahead and use the ID to join that table with payments one.

What are other options? Maybe some is better or/and easier to maintain. This database will be used with C# program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use separate year and quarter instead of a date (since you seem to have specific reporting requirements), I would go for a `tinyint` for quarter and `smallint` for year and store them in the `PAYMENT` table itself.

I would not store it in a different table. This is bad since:

- You have to make sure you have produced enough years/quarters
- You have to join and use a foreign key

If you store the data with the record, **it will help performance on reads.** Your table could be small but it is always good to keep in mind performance.

## WHY

Let's imagine you need to get

> all payments in specific quarter
>   where payment has been more than
>   specific amount and customer is a
>   particular customer

In this case, you would need a **covering index** on all items and still does not help since your query is for specific quarter and not quarter year. Having the data on the table, however, will help with lighter execution plan.

Comment: For each payment or with table join ? Database will be small (less then 1GB i think).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and clear explanation. I'll accept your answer as soon as Stack will let me :)

Answer (score 3):

I've always just used datetime value with the 1st of January/April/July/October representing each quarter. Makes computation of the start/end dates of the quarter simple:

- Start Date: the `datetime` column itself.
- End Data: `dateadd(month,3,quarterColumn)`

Another alternative would be [ISO 8601](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf). Here's an ISO 8601 profile for use in Internet protocols: [RFC 3339](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) (proposed standard).

An ISO 8601 representation of each quarter of the year 2011 looks like this:

- 2011-01-01/P3M
- 2011-04-01/P3M
- 2011-07-01/P3M
- 2011-10-01/P3M

The above specify a duration by starting date and duration (in this case, 3 months).

The advantage of ISO 8601 date/time formats is that the strings are (A) human readable, (B) they collate properly, (C) they're easy to parse and (D) its an international standard.

Some people "extend" ISO 8601's week notation, where a week of the year looks like `2011W32` (the 32nd week of 2011), to a quarter notation. Using this unofficial extension, the quarters of the year 2011 looks like:

- 2011Q1
- 2011Q2
- 2011Q3
- 2011Q4

Answer (score 2):

How about using [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) based on the payment date?  I'd rather do this than have both a date and quarter/year that might get out of sync.  On the other hand, I suppose it's possible that you may need the ability to have a different year/quarter than the date indicates in which case you'd need to keep them separate.  I'd at least think about using computed columns though as that seems the best way to ensure integrity.

Comment: Payment date wouldn't work. Usually employee will record the payment after the quarter is already over. I would need to store false date or last day of the quarter to use this.

Comment: IMO, this is the right approach. Imagine if they change from quarters by calendar year to quarters by fiscal year. Far better to have the logic of how the quarter buckets are determined in one place that can easily be changed.

Comment: @MadBoy - I think you are thinking of two different dates. One date clearly relates to the quarter (perhaps date received?). The other date relates to when it was entered. Those should be separate. It *should* be the case that if the payment date (the first one I described) is changed, the quarter changes with it.

Comment: There won't be changes like this. We have customers that will need to get invoices once every quarter for 12 quarters or so. I need to be able to distinguish if the payment was already done, if not then create invoice. If yes, ignore.

Comment: @MadBoy - I'm not thinking of the date on which the payment was recorded but the date on which it was received/invoiced -- whatever the accountant uses to keep things straight.

Comment: What is the actual event represented by this date? The date it was posted? cleared? received? Whatever that event is, the rule that puts into the appropriate quarter bucket should be a rule not data since the rule could easily change.

Comment: Well, employee will create invoice/create payment for 1st quarter in 2nd quarter. That means I will have date lets say '2011-04-05' and will let the employee to choose which quarter he wants to create invoice for. So I can either save last day of quarter or just simply tinyint with quarter number and smallint with date. But it can very much be that someone "forgets" to make invoice and it will be sent quarter later.

Comment: Btw, this brings up another point. it is not hard to see different reports that put payments in different quarter buckets by using different events to determine in which bucket they should go depending on the person for whom the report is made.

Comment: @MadBoy - That could make it difficult to determine why a given payment is in a given quarter. If you go back and review the data a year later, you won't know why a given payment is in Q1 v Q2. It could have been a mistake in the app. It could have been a conscious decision. It could have been a database update. No way to easily know.

Answer (score 1):

For something so simple, I would just keep 2 int columns, and to build up the (pivotal) dates using dateadd when required to use date ranges.

Another option is a single date column, for which you can store the first day in the quarter, so the 4 dates in a year would be 1-Jan, 1-Apr, 1-Jul, 1-Oct.  You can extract the quarter, year easily using datepart Q and Y.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with tinyint and int.

Answer (score 1):

How about two ints, one for the year, and one for the quarter (1-4). Is that what you meant by option "a"?

Option "b" would work, but you have to remember to maintain the table every year or so.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought about option a :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree two ints are fine.

I would add an index consisting of both columns in case you need to sort or filter by year and quarter.

Answer (score 1):

You could even use a single `tinyint`. It's enough for storing in the form YYQ,like 111, 112,113,114, 121...for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Storing quarter and year in database depends on how your payment data is being organized. Examples would be; how many different payment values are being inserted. Will the quarter/year ranges vary? etc.

One good technique for "defining" a quarter/year range is making a separate table with a "DateTime" field that identifies a quarter. You don't need to join the table, you just need to do programming in C# to figure out if the range falls within a particular pay quarter.

For example:

```
Table 1: Payments
-----------------
paymentID (int)
paymentAmount (double(7,2))
paymentDateTime (DateTime)

Table 2: QuarterYear
--------------------
quarterYearID (int)
dateFrom (date)
dateTo (date)
quarter (tinyint)
description (varchar)
```

Example Data

```
paymentID | paymentAmount |   paymentDateTime
------------------------------------------------
    1     |    20.24      |  2011-04-18 08:14:20
    2     |    34.15      |  2011-04-19 07:42:15
    3     |    51.87      |  2011-04-20 13:04:22

quarterYearID |  dateFrom  |   dateTo   | quarter |  description
-----------------------------------------------------------------
      1       | 2011-01-01 | 2011-03-31 |    1    | first quarter
      2       | 2011-04-01 | 2011-06-30 |    2    | second quarter 
      3       | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-31 |    3    | third quarter
      4       | 2011-10-01 | 2011-12-31 |    4    | forth quarter
```

Example Query for getting all payments for "Quarter 2"
dateValue is a dynamically pulled variable from the payments table. C# will handle 'dateValue' value.

```
SELECT quarter FROM QuarterYear WHERE cast('dateValue' AS date) BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo;
```

Comment: Aliostad had a decent suggestion, if you wish to define the quarters with the code. My recommendation is how you can define/edit quarters dynamically within a database. There is no need to join the tables.