# Store Quarter/Year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which needs to store the quarter and year, and I need to know which is the best way to do this. I found this answer from 10 years ago on SO: [Best way to store quarter and year in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709247/best-way-to-store-quarter-and-year-in-sql-server). However, there are two suggestions given--one is storing quarter and year in separate columns and making them integers, the other being storing as a datetime and using the first day of the month for the day (i.e., 1/1/2021, 4/1/2021, etc.).

Considering this answer is 10 years old and there could be better ways now for storing this data, what is the best method?

FYI, this data will not be used for calculation purposes, but will probably be searched on.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't make a huge amount of difference, but `date` rather than `datetime`. Although querying is more complex with two columns, maybe it's easier to comprehend. Whatever you do, don't store them in `varchar` and don't store them in one field as an int `202101`.

Comment: It depends greatly on your queries. Both of these approaches can be better or worse depending on the needs. For storage purposes it's almost non-issue, since a `DATE` and `SMALLINT` + `TINYINT` combo both take up 3 bytes. For indexing and calculation purposes there may be quite a difference. In terms of data integrity, storing only what is legal (i.e. actual quarters, not arbitrary dates) may be yet another concern. The 10 years that have passed since the original question haven't really made a difference with regards to any of these issues. Computed columns can make up for the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend always storing date related data as the datetime data type.

Storing them separately is the worst possible approach, searching becomes very difficult.  Try writing the query returning all quarters between 3Q2019 and 1Q2021 when your year and quarter are separate.

Breaking it into separate parts puts the responsibility on the developer to handle the year boundary appropriately, which many do not.

DateTime data type also includes validation (Q5 2020 would throw an error) to prevent data errors.

Use the right tool for the job.  DateTime data should always be stored in a DateTime datatype.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, Jeroen, and Wes for your comments. This is another one of those topics where there will be a lot of differing opinions, I guess, and I see merit in all of them. Wes, your explanation makes a lot of sense. I think I will end up using DATE. Then the developer who codes the interface can make the column appear however the client wishes.